# How to add up new textfield to the existing textfield-iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uitableview, uitextfield

I am creating an iphone application, where i am getting confuse. I wants to implement a field as i have mention in below screenshots.

[image]

[image]

By default, it should display one text field, where user can enter his email. Again if user will press on add button, it will show one new textfield gets add up below the existing field. It is possible with table view, is it good way to implement it with table view or i need to do with any other way?

Even i have seen in iphone device address book such type of fields, when we will add new contacts in device, it display by default home phone number. Once enter it again it will show next field which is office phone number and so on..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can two it by UITableView as well as UIScrollView and if there is limit in add functionality then no need of any of them.

Comment: @eptdeveloperThanks, there is no limit. I cant use table view bcoz i hv to implement this many places in same view.

Comment: then i suggst you to go with scrollview and set the contentSize of scrollview every time you add new textfield

Answer (score 0):

I'm not real experienced with this myself, but my guess is that adding a table view would be best.

You could also add a certain number of hidden text fields below the current text field, and when the button is pressed they are shown (the property to change is .hidden). But I don't think that would be ideal.

Comment: @DonyorMThanks for your reply bro but there is no limit, user can enter according to his need.

Comment: hide/show is not a good option for dynamic number of textfields

Comment: Yeah, that's why I said it wasn't ideal.

Comment: i am totally agree with u, even how can developer knows for users need?

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to list another option said I don't know tons about this.

Answer (score 0):

`UITableView` should be indeed the easiest way. You can use a `NSMutableArray` with your current TextFields as datasource for the tableView.

Each time the user taps in the button, just allocate a new textfield, add in the array and add a new cell for the tableview.

Comment: @LucasThanks, but in my single view, i am implementing such type of field more than 3 or 4 places. i have updated my question..

Comment: I saw your edit now. What do you mean by "implementing such type of field more than 3 or 4 places"? And I still think that you can play with a tableView to achieve what you want

Comment: @LucasYes, you are totally correct. Finally i am doing it by using custom table view cell. Thanks for giving me time..

Comment: You are welcome. Your question was to broad to give more informations, but any doubts you can ask, I'd glad to help